# 'd' instead of 'days' in Django naturaltime

Tags: python, django, humanize

I'm workin in a mobile application with DRF as backend and using `naturaltime` built-in function, but since this is a mobile app, screen space is a big problem (atleast for me). So for an arbitrary date I get:

```
"1 week, 2 days ago"
```

Which is nice, but I wonder if it is possible get

```
"1w, 2d ago"
```

I know I could replace words in string, but I hope there's a better way. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best way to do this would be to “localize” the names. <s>You might want to look at the [source of `django.contrib.humanize`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/humanize/templatetags/humanize.py). To translate, **back up** and change the file at `django/contrib/humanize/locale/<your language>/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`, particularly starting at line 240. Then, run `manage.py compilemessages` to update the `.mo` files.</s>

#### EDIT:

An alternate way to do this is without altering the Django installation is:

1. Add the following lines to `settings.py`, unless you have already done so:

   ```
   LOCALE_PATHS = (
       "/path/to/my/project/locale/",
   )
   ```
2. Add a subdirectory called `en` to the above path
3. Add a file called `django.po` to the `en` directory you just created.
4. Paste the [contents of the `naturaltime` translations](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/humanize/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po#L238-L307) into the file.
5. Change them to your liking.
6. Run `manage.py compilemessages` to update the `.mo` files *from the directory that* `manage.py` *is in*, then wait for the changes to propagate.

Comment: This sounds pro, I like it. But when I update the code in the production server, will this take effect? What if I take the `humanize.py` and rewrite the involved code?

Comment: If you update `humanize.py`, it will invalidate the translation files because you have changed the `msgid` text.. This should probably take effect on the production server if you run `manage.py compilemessages` unless you are using caches. If you are using caches, you may have to wait for them to expire.

Comment: `.mo` files are compiled translations that are not meant to be edited. A `.po` file contains, for each translation, a line starting with `msgid` that is the text in the translation function, and a line starting with `msgstr` that is the translated version. There are also more complicated syntaxes for different things, including pluralization.

Comment: So if I modifiy something I could broken translations or pluralizations..?

Comment: Only if you changed the text in the translation strings ([example](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/humanize/templatetags/humanize.py#L235-L239)).

Comment: I like your solution, but I am not sure the future consequences.

Comment: What do you mean by “future consequences?”

Comment: `django/contrib/humanize/locale/<your language>/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` is not tracked by git. I have to do the same in my server?

Comment: What do you mean by “not tracked by git?” If you are using the GitHub repo, the URL for the English one is [django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/humanize/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/humanize/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po)

Comment: I mean, you suggest I modify a django file, but those files are not the same that in my production server, because in my prod. server there's another django installation, so I would have to do the same modification in my prod. server, right?

Comment: Yes. you would also have to modify the production server’s installation.

Comment: And every new installation... And if Django changes something could stop working.

Comment: Wow, it looks nice and makes sense. Should I copy the lines that you highlighted or the complete file?

Comment: If you just want to customize `naturaltime`, those lines will suffice.

Comment: I can not give it a try right now, because I am working in other issue, but I will and accept it if it works. Thank you for your patience and support.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this shortnaturaltime filter. 
https://github.com/ollieglass/django-shortnaturaltime

Comment: Yes, thanks, I found it but I think it is not being maintained anymore.

Comment: Also, this is a template tag.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like something you can customise:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/humanize/templatetags/humanize.py#L189